# bind member function to a function object

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm trying to set signal handler for some signals:

```
std::function<void(int)> signalHandlerCallback;

MyApp app;
signalHandlerCallback = std::bind(std::mem_fn(&MyApp::SignalHandler, &app, std::placeholders::_1)); // *

// ...
class MyApp
{
public:
    void SignalHandler(int signum);
};
```

and compiler produces the following error (at line *):

```
test.cpp:53:111: error: no matching function for call to 'mem_fn(void (MyApp::*)(int), MyApp*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&)'
```

The same error appears if I don't specify the placeholder.

So how can I bind member function to a std::function in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `std::mem_fn`. Just rewrite it this way:

```
signalHandlerCallback = std::bind(&MyApp::SignalHandler, &app, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Comment: @RedXIII, I didn't forget. SO permits accepting an answer for some time (in my case it was 11 minutes), so I went back to my work. Incredibly fast and accurate answer. Of course I accept this.